# magento 2 how can we send shipment and invoice pdf attachment in one email

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, mageplaza

i want to attach invoice pdf with shipment email so how can we attach invoice pdf in shipment email as i am using magento 2 mageplaza pdfinvoice module. it attach only one pdf at one time.

Answer (score 0):

Path : `Magento root directory/app/code/Mageplaza/PdfInvoice/Model/Template/SenderBuilder.php`

***Replace This file from mageplaza pdfinvoice module***

```
<?php
/**
 * Mageplaza
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Mageplaza.com license that is
 * available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * https://mageplaza.com/LICENSE.txt
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade this extension to newer
 * version in the future.
 *
 * @category    Mageplaza
 * @package     Mageplaza_PdfInvoice
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2017-2018 Mageplaza (https://www.mageplaza.com/)
 * @license     http://mageplaza.com/LICENSE.txt
 */

namespace Mageplaza\PdfInvoice\Model\Template;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Mageplaza\PdfInvoice\Helper\Data;
use Mageplaza\PdfInvoice\Helper\PrintProcess;
use Mageplaza\PdfInvoice\Model\Source\Type;
use Zend\Mail\Message as Message;
use Zend\Mime\Mime;
use Zend\Mime\Part as MimePart;


use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilderByStore;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\IdentityInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MailMessageInterface;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\SenderResolverInterface;
/**
 * Class SenderBuilder
 * @package Mageplaza\PdfInvoice\Model\Template
 */
class SenderBuilder extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder
{ 
    /**
     * @var SenderResolverInterface
     */
    protected $senderResolver;

    public function __construct(
        Template $templateContainer,
        IdentityInterface $identityContainer,
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        SenderResolverInterface $senderResolver,
        array $attachments = []
    ) {
        /** @var MessageInterface $message */
        $message = $objectManager->create(\Ebizmarts\Mandrill\Model\Message::class);
        /** @var TransportBuilder $transportBuilder */
        $transportBuilder = $objectManager->create(
            TransportBuilder::class,
            ["message" => $message]
        );
        /** @var TransportBuilderByStore $transportBuilderByStore */
        $transportBuilderByStore = $objectManager->create(
            TransportBuilderByStore::class,
            ["message" => $message]
        );
        parent::__construct($templateContainer, $identityContainer, $transportBuilder, $transportBuilderByStore);
        $this->senderResolver = $senderResolver;
    }
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
   public function send()
    {

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info(get_class($this->transportBuilder));
        $this->attachPDF();
        parent::send();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function sendCopyTo()
    {
        $this->attachPDF();
        parent::sendCopyTo();
    }

    protected function configureEmailTemplate()
    {
        parent::configureEmailTemplate();
        $this->transportBuilder->setFrom(
            $this->senderResolver->resolve(
                $this->identityContainer->getEmailIdentity(),
                $this->identityContainer->getStore()->getId()
            )
        );
    }
    /**
     * Attach pdf
     */
    public function attachPDF()
    {
        $objectManager = ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $configHelper  = $objectManager->get(Data::class);

        $templateVars = $this->templateContainer->getTemplateVars();
        $store        = $templateVars['store'];

        if ($configHelper->isEnabled($store->getId())) {
            try {
                $dataHelper = $objectManager->get(PrintProcess::class);
                $content2 = null;
                $fileName2 = null;
                if (isset($templateVars['invoice'])) {
                    $invoice  = $templateVars['invoice'];
                    $templateVars = array_merge($templateVars,$dataHelper->getDataProcess(Type::INVOICE, $invoice->getId()));

                    $content  = $dataHelper->processPDFTemplate(Type::INVOICE, $templateVars, $store->getId());
                    $fileName = 'Invoice' . $invoice->getIncrementId();
                } else if (isset($templateVars['shipment'])) {
                    /* Main Logic Start from here*/    
                    $shipment = $templateVars['shipment'];
                    $templateVars = array_merge($templateVars,$dataHelper->getDataProcess(Type::SHIPMENT, $shipment->getId()));
                    $content  = $dataHelper->processPDFTemplate(Type::SHIPMENT, $templateVars, $store->getId());
                    $fileName = 'Shipment' . $shipment->getIncrementId();

                    $order = $shipment->getOrder();
                    if ($order->hasInvoices()) {
                        foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $invoice) {
                            $templateVars = array_merge($templateVars,$dataHelper->getDataProcess(Type::INVOICE, $invoice->getId()));
                            $content2 = $dataHelper->processPDFTemplate(Type::INVOICE, $templateVars, $store->getId());
                            $fileName2 = 'Invoice' . $invoice->getIncrementId();
                            if ($content2) {
                                $this->transportBuilder->addAttachment(
                                    $content2,
                                    'application/pdf',
                                    \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                                    \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                                    $fileName2 . '.pdf'
                                );
                            }
                        }   
                    }

                } else if (isset($templateVars['creditmemo'])) {
                    $creditmemo = $templateVars['creditmemo'];
                    $content    = $dataHelper->processPDFTemplate(Type::CREDIT_MEMO, $templateVars, $store->getId());
                    $fileName   = 'Creditmemo' . $creditmemo->getIncrementId();
                } else {
                    $order    = $templateVars['order'];
                    $fileName = 'Order' . $order->getIncrementId();
                    $content  = $dataHelper->processPDFTemplate(Type::ORDER, $templateVars, $store->getId());
                }

                if ($content) {
                    $this->transportBuilder->addAttachment(
                        $content,
                        'application/pdf',
                        \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                        \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                        $fileName . '.pdf'
                    );
                }

            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/pdfinvoice.log');
                $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
                $logger->addWriter($writer);
                $logger->info($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```